# Cointegration Testing in F#

Tags: f#, statistics

Hi I was wondering if there are any packages for doing time series cointegration testing in fsharp.

In particular is there any package that implements the augmented dickey fuller test.

Similar to python's statsmodels.tsa, or R's urca.

Answer (score 2):

One of the options is to run R libraries directly from F# with [R Type Provider](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/FSharpRProvider)

Comment: And the R provider also integrates nicely with Deedle - which is a time-series and data frame library for C# and F#. Check out: http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/rinterop.html